# Limiting number of lines in a String dynamically

Tags: android, string, lines

I have a String which is a long paragraph. I am displaying this string into various items of a ListView.

I want the every alternate item of the listview to have dynamic number of lines/ words in the string. Eg. If first item has 2 lines, 2nd item should have 3 lines.

This is my code:-

```
mydescription = mydescription.substring(0, Math.min(mydescription.length(), 50));
viewHolder.description.setText(mydescription);
mydescription =Html.fromHtml(song.getBody()).toString();
```

How can I do this?

Comment: what about item on 3rd, 4th, 5th, etc?

Comment: sounds like a task in a class. Or do you want to word wrap your string into the listviews?

Comment: what is the problem then?

Comment: @ariefbayu. It should continuew that way alternating between 2 and 3 lines

Comment: @thst yes I want to word wrap my string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have one idea that is with item

```
    Position
```

of item. Suppose Item that means

```
   Position ==0 and Line number =2 and Position == 1 then Line number =3
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use substring or subsequence, with indexof(newlinechar, startfrom).

code should be something like this, I havent tested it, please test and verify

```
String skipLines(String in, int numLines){
    int newlineIndex = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<numLines; i++){
        newlineIndex = in.indexOf('\n', newlineIndex);
    }
    try {
        return new String(in.substring(0, newlineIndex));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // probably we reached end of string, return the whole string
        e.printStackTrace();
        return in;
    }
}
```

Comment: i get a error `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=211; regionStart=0; regionLength=408`

Comment: This code doesnt handle any exceptions, I thought you could add that.